# Error in my Controller [AngularJs]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm getting the following message error: Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined

Here is my mainController.js file:

```
angular.module("elcomaApp", []).controller('MainController', ['$scope',     'ElcomaService', function($scope, ElcomaService){
    $scope.name = 'Natanael Santos';
    console.log($scope.name);
    ElcomaService.sucess(function(data){
        $scope.elcomaData = data;
    })
}]);
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("elcomaApp", ['MainController', 'ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'MainController',
        templateUrl: 'views/timeline.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

Here is my service.js file:

```
angular.module("elcomaApp", []).factory('ElcomaService', ['$http', function($http){
    return $http.get('http://vagalumewifi.com.br/timeline.json')
    .success(function(data){

    })
    .error(function(err){
        return err;
    });
}]);
```

And my index.html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="elcomaApp" ng-controller="MainController" ng-cloak>


    <md-toolbar class="md-hue-2">
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings" ng-disabled="true">
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/menu.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <h2>
          <span>{{ name }}</span>
        </h2>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Favorite">
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/favorite.svg" style="color: greenyellow;"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="More">
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/more_vert.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>

    <div ng-view></div>




  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/mainController.js"></script>
  <script src="services/elcomaService.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why is your `MainController` listed as a dependency for your own app? You're already writing it within your `elcomaApp` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module("elcomaApp", ['MainController', 'ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);
```

In this statement , remove `MainController`.

It is already defined on `elcomaApp` and no need to DI for it.It is always available.

Correction :

`

```
angular.module("elcomaApp", []).factory`  // will override the module defination

`angular.module("elcomaApp").factory('`  //correct way
```

Comment: The problem was the overriding  module definition. Thank you :D

Comment: Why it is correct to put the "[]" in controler file:     angular.module("elcomaApp", []).controller...

Comment: In order to initaliaze or create the new module,one should provide `[]` either empty or list of DI.To get this module just need module name.

Answer (score 1):

In your app.js file, the first line

`var app = angular.module("elcomaApp", ['MainController', 'ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);`

Is saying that your app is dependent on the 'MainController' module, which is in turn dependent on your app. It won't work. You only need to add dependencies in to your app for external modules. Your module is "elcomaApp", and already includes your 'MainController'

Change that line to

`var app = angular.module("elcomaApp", ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);`

And it should work.